# git hub branches

Tags: github, branch

I am using github and I have the following question,  I have a master branch and I created a new branch out of master by doing

```
Git branch {branchname"
Git checkout {branchname}.
```

Now I need to edit some settings file , should I edit this file from my new branch or the Master? If I edit it from the new branch, then each time I create a new branch for different projects, then I should be modifying this settings file…but at the same time if I edit it by being on master branch, then when I merge/update master branch later, then I would loose the changes. Can someone please clarify the best way to handle this? If I have to do it from Master, then how I can stash it as I never push anything from master branch.

Comment: Settings for your project or for your git repository?

Comment: the file is located inside a folder which is part of the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends what you want.  If you want the new settings to be available everywhere, you need to modify the file in master, check it in, then rebase any existing branches to get the settings.

If you only want the changes in the other branch, make them there.  If you ever merge the other branch back into master, then master will then have them.

Comment: thanks, what you said is correct. this is what I did now - I made the changes in master branch and stashed them as I dont want my changes to merge with the original. the reason I did not do it on a specific branch is because each time when I create a branch out of master, I have to make the changes again.